# Prove $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}[n,\infty)\ne\varnothing$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}[n,\infty)\ne\varnothing$$
I do not understand how the intersection is not empty if for every $x$ in the intersection there is $n>x$.

Comment: Don't worry. It is EMPTY!

Comment: `is not empty` What makes you think it's *not* empty?

Comment: I believe that since n+1>n then n+1 is contained in [n, infinite) For every n in N, hence n+1 is contained in the intersection.

Comment: @AnaPauDelaFuente Think about any one fixed number $N$. If $N$ was in each one of those, then that would mean that $N\ge n$ for *all* natural numbers $n$. Does that make sense?

Comment: @CameronWilliams but that would mean that the intersection is not empty right?

Comment: @AnaPauDelaFuente `I believe that` That doesn't have any bearing on the intersection being empty or not. Fact is that any $n$ occurs in exactly $n$ of those intervals, so the infinite intersection of *all* of them cannot contain any finite $n$, and therefore is empty.

Comment: @AnaPauDelaFuente you might be thinking of $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^N[n,\infty)$.  Indeed, $N+1\in\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^N[n,\infty)$ and $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^N[n,\infty)$ is not empty.  The question is however about the *infinite* intersection, and in the *infinite* intersection $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty[n,\infty)=\emptyset$ is actually empty.

Comment: @JMoravitz Could you elaborate more on this?

Comment: Lets look at just the integers for now... The intersection you are talking about is $\{1,2,3,4,\dots\}\cap \{2,3,4,\dots\}\cap \{3,4,\dots\}\cap \{4,\dots\}\cap\dots$.  Take your favorite integer... say, a billion.  It will be in the first billion of these sets, and if we were looking at the finite intersections of the first however many sets, one-billion will be in each and every one of those and so will be in the intersection when looking at those... *BUT*... we are looking at the *infinite* intersection... and eventually, we will be intersecting with a set whose smallest number is bigger...

Comment: In general, if you have *any* collection of sets $A_1,A_2,A_3,\dots$ then $\bigcup\limits_{n\in \Bbb N}A_n=\left\{x~:~\text{there is at least one}~n~\text{such that}~x\in A_n\right\}$ and $\bigcap\limits_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n=\left\{x~:~x~\text{is in}~A_n~\text{for ALL values of}~n\right\}$.  Since one-billion is not in $[10^{100},\infty)$ for example, in your original problem that implies that one-billion is not in the final resulting set.  Indeed, for *any* value of $x$ we see that $x$ is not an element of $[\lfloor x\rfloor +2,\infty)$.  $x$ is in only finitely many sets and not in the others.